# Create an Outlook appointment IF a cell contains certain text

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a new Outlook appointment with Excel data, if a cell contains the word "Yes".

```
Sub AddAppointments()

' Create the Outlook session
Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Start at row 4    
r = 4

Do Until Trim(Cells(r, 1).Value) = ""

    ' Create the AppointmentItem
    Set myApt = myOutlook.CreateItem(1)

    ' Set the appointment properties
    myApt.Subject = Cells(r, 3).Value
    myApt.Start = Cells(r, 7) + Cells(r, 8).Value

    If Trim(Cells(r, 5).Value) = "" Then
        myApt.BusyStatus = 2
    Else
        myApt.BusyStatus = Cells(r, 5).Value
    End If

    If Cells(r, 10).Value = "Yes" Then
        myApt.ReminderSet = True
    Else
        myApt.ReminderSet = False
    End If

    myApt.Body = "£" & Cells(r, 6).Value
        myApt.Save
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

If the cell contains "No", or "N/A" it stops. I would like it to ignore those.

Comment: Always use `Option Explicit` and fully declare your variables. Rather than using a `Do` loop, get the row count then use a `FOR` loop. Always use qualified workbook/worksheets. When you say `Cells(r, 10).Value`, you are looking at whatever the active sheet is (which may not be the sheet you want to look at). Also, `If Cells(r, 10).Value = "Yes" Then` should be the first thing you do in the loop

Comment: I picked up most of that code from elsewhere, it's nothing that I've ever tried before - I only want to look at the active sheets but have no idea about Option Explicit?

Comment: `Option Explicit` forces you to declare your variables. If you don't declare a variable, in VBA, the variable is set are a variant **`type`**. This could give you unwanted results

Comment: Also, a `FOR `loop - how would I incorporate that?  Like I say, I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: A simple working example has been uploaded to dropbox. please go through it. It is yet to be worked out for certain options. <https://www.dropbox.com/s/zii6rghcc99zfqt/55378123-trying-to-import-excel-data-as-an-outlook-appointment.xlsm?dl=0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample example worksheet snapshot is appended below.
[image]

Following example code works for me .

```
Option Explicit    
Sub test2()

        Dim OL As Outlook.Application, Appoint As Outlook.AppointmentItem, ES As Worksheet, _
        r As Long, i As Long, WB As ThisWorkbook

        Set WB = ThisWorkbook
        Set ES = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")
        r = ES.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set OL = New Outlook.Application
    For i = 2 To r
        Set Appoint = OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        With Appoint
            .Subject = ES.Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Start = ES.Cells(i, 2).Value
            .End = ES.Cells(i, 3).Value
            .Location = ES.Cells(i, 4).Value
            .AllDayEvent = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
            .Categories = ES.Cells(i, 6).Value & " Category"
            .BusyStatus = ES.Cells(i, 7).Value
            .ReminderSet = True
            .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
            .Body = ES.Cells(i, 8).Value
            .Save
        End With
    Next i
     Set OL = Nothing

    End Sub
```

**Edit**

Based on OP's comments , putting "Needs Chasing" in `Column10` . Revised code works out as follows.

```
Sub test3()

    Dim OL As Outlook.Application, Appoint As Outlook.AppointmentItem, ES As Worksheet, _
    r As Long, i As Long, WB As ThisWorkbook

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    r = ES.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application
For i = 2 To r
    If ES.Cells(i, 10) = "Yes" Then
    Set Appoint = OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    With Appoint
        .Subject = ES.Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Start = ES.Cells(i, 2).Value
        .End = ES.Cells(i, 3).Value
        .Location = ES.Cells(i, 4).Value
        .AllDayEvent = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
        .Categories = ES.Cells(i, 6).Value & " Category"
        .BusyStatus = ES.Cells(i, 7).Value
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
        .Body = ES.Cells(i, 8).Value
        .Save
    End With
    End If
Next i
 Set OL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I get it to ignore a cell with False in?

Comment: @ffc2004 I shall try to incorporate that situation. Which item you want to check. Is it BusyStatus.

Comment: In the worksheet I'm trying to use it in, it's a column named "Needs Chasing" - I only want it to add an appointment for those that say "Yes"

Comment: @ffc2004 Please see my edit. incorporating condition of "Needs Chasing" column.

Comment: I'm getting "Compile Error - User-defined type not defined" for the section `OL As Outlook.Application`

Comment: @ffc2004  I think you have to add reference to Outlook Object Library. Go to VB Editor `Tools` tab . In `Tools` tab goto `References` then search for 'Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library` or other version number as per your system and check it to select.Please note that you can add references when you come out of debugging mode. In case of difficulty try out my sample file <https://www.dropbox.com/s/izlebd8ffmldyko/55378123-trying-to-import-excel-data-V2.xlsm?dl=0> after correcting version number of outlook library.

Comment: That's great, thank you. Another query I have, should you be able to help, is this - is there any way to get it to skip any appointments that have previously been added?

Comment: @ffc2004 If my answer helped you. Please accept my answer . To accept the answer please click on the check mark beside the answer below down pointing triangle to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.. Regarding your other point I understand you want to delete the appointment.Some thing like this continued...

Comment: @ffc2004   somt thing like this `sFilter = "[Start] = '" & Format(OutlookStartTime, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & _
    "' And [End] = '" & Format(OutlookEndTime, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' " & _
    " And [Subject] = '" & Me.AP_With_Whom & " - " & Me.AP_Type & "'"`
  
 ` Set objAppointment = objAppointments.items.Find(sFilter)`
  
 ` If Not TypeName(objAppointment) = "Nothing" Then`
  `  objAppointment.Delete`
`  End If`

Comment: I'm not sure where I'd place that code? Also it stated that  _ and ` were invalid characters, and invalid use of Me keyword

Comment: @ffc2004 I am giving here a link which shall help you to place correct syntax in place.<https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6007cd79-d17b-42d3-8c51-57c775bd3371/find-and-delete-outlook-calendar-item-using-vba?forum=accessdev>

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Sub AppointmentAutomation()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim oPattern As RecurrencePattern
    Set oAppt = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    Set oPattern = oAppt.GetRecurrencePattern
    With oPattern
        .RecurrenceType = olRecursWeekly
        .DayOfWeekMask = olMonday
        .PatternStartDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
        .PatternEndDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
        .Duration = 60
        .StartTime = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
        .EndTime = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2")
    End With
    oAppt.Subject = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")
    oAppt.Save
    oAppt.Display

Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]